# Set the media type for an iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Suppose I have the following document displayed in an iframe:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
        @media print { body { color: blue; } }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>Hi!</body>
</html>
```

Is there a way to set the iframe's media type to print, so the body color style is activated?

Comment: could you add a class to one of the elements?

Comment: This is for an app that creates html pages.  The user types all the css so I can't easily modify that.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, it is not possible to use HTML to / iframes to request a specific @media type. I'd back this up with the follow extension to Firefox developer tools, which explicitly needed to code an API to emulate different media types:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=819930

Perhaps using SASS or LESS you can avoid copy and pasting all the **print** code, and nest everything in a **body.media-print {}** block, allowing you to write the code once, and display it by just adding the media-print class to your body when emulating print mode.

Comment: I second that advice - if possible just create a body class `print`, which is also useful for a print preview type page too.